# Replace old O365 Suite Bar with the new one in SharePoint Online

Tags: .net, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm looking to replace the old O365 Suite Bar with the new one for my SharePoint Online Addin project. Any pointers?

Old :

[Old Suite Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0pb1.png)

New :

[New Suite Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj3fs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll have to inject the Office 365 java script to get the new suit-bar. Following is the article explains the detail procedure.
https://www.itunity.com/article/integrating-office-365-suite-bar-app-launcher-2694